# zend newbie - pushing values back to form in a view

Tags: zend-framework

Using a regular HTML form (not Zend form), how do I push the value of a posted variable back to the form on re-display. Is there a zend way of doing this?

```
controller:
$name = $f->filter($this->_request->getPost('your_name'));
$this->view->your_name = $name;


view:
<form action=""  method="post">
Name:<br><input type="text" value="<?value goes here?>" name="your_name" ><br>
Email:<br><input type="text" value="" name="your_email"><br>
Comment:<br><textarea name="your_comment"></textarea><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"><br>
</form>
```

**answer:**

in controller:
$this->view->your_name = $name;

in view:

your_name?>

Answer (score 0):

in view:

```
$this->your_name;
```

at form:

```
Name:<br><input type="text" value="<?= $this->your_name ?>" name="your_name" ><br>
```